# Store global reference to a service/object

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, .net

In developing with ArcMap, is there any way to register a service that can be used during the life-cycle of a document- for example to do something like:

C# .NET

```
mxApplication.RegisterService(myWebService);
```

then later-

```
mxApplication.GetService<WebService>().SaySomething("Hi");
```

So kind of using the Service Locator pattern or similar.

Comment: Just as @blah238 mentioned- found [this](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000zz000000) source that clarifies where/how to coordinate different components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically in AO you would use an extension to manage state and listen for the OpenDocument, CloseDocument, etc. events. See the [Extension to listen to document open and save events sample](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000004r1000000) for example.

If you need to persist data in the map document itself, see the [How to persist data in a document](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_persist_data_in_a_document/00010000027z000000/) sample.

Comment: Thanks. I created an Extension and publicly declared and initialized objects that tools and menus share as static members. Now I have 'global' access as long as the Extension is loaded.